# How can I make my library compatible with libraries that use Proxies

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, proxy, es6-class

I've written a library that relies on equality checks. Example:

```js
export class Item {
  constructor(opts) {
    if (typeof opts.name !== 'string') throw new TypeError('Name should be a string');
    if (!opts.name) throw new Error('Please give item a name');
    this.name = opts.name;
    this.active = typeof opts.active === 'boolean' ? opts.active : false;
  }

  activate() {
    this.active = true;
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.active = false;
  }
}

export class Stage {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.items = [];
  }
  
  add(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  activate(itemToActivate) {
    // Strict equality check here
    const found = this.items.find(i => i === itemToActivate);
    if (!found) throw new Error('Item "${itemToActivate.name}" not found');
    found.activate();
  }
}
```

Using this library could look like this:

```js
import { Item, Stage } from 'lib.js';

const stage = new Stage();
const item1 = new Item({ name: 'one' });
const item2 = new Item({ name: 'two' });
stage.add(item1);
stage.add(item2);
stage.activate(item2);
```

This all works fine, but I'm running into issues when using this library in a framework that works with proxied objects like Vue 3, since I'm using a strict equality test in the `activate` method of the `Stage` class.

For example, in Vue 3:

```
<script>
import { Item, Stage } from 'lib.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stage: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.stage = new Stage();
    const item1 = new Item({ name: 'one' });
    const item2 = new Item({ name: 'two' });
    stage.add(item1);
    stage.add(item2);
    stage.activate(item2); // This will throw an error `Item "two" not found`
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="stage">
    <div>Items:</div>
    <div v-for="(item, idx) in stage.items">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </div>
<template>
```

From what I understand, Vue 3 and other frameworks' use of Proxy introduce a caveat to be aware of: the proxied object is not equal to the original object in terms of identity comparison (===), which is why `activate` throws an Error.

My question is: how do I update my library so it supports Proxy-based frameworks without using any framework helpers like [toRaw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) which would make my library dependent on that framework?

Comment: Once you hand your objects over to Vue3 as props, Vue3 proxies and they are no longer yours. Those proxies as part of Vue's reactivity feature set. Specifically so the props can be watched and updates provided when the props change. Since Vue is doing this, it owns the proxies and is in control, you must ask Vue to undo this and regain control of your objects to treat them as "your" objects (`toRaw()`). Otherwise, you'll need to `Reflect` on those properties and test each individually for equality.

Comment: thank you for your answer @RandyCasburn. I understand the reason behind the equality check failing due to Vue working with proxies to enable reactivity. However I'm looking for a way to update my library to support any framework that uses Proxies for reactivity, without requiring the consumer of my library to do any changes. I'm okay with the the references to `Item` being proxied, but I need assistance on how to circumvent the strict equality error.

Comment: You'll have to introspect the input object's properties and test each individual property for equivalence. Sorry I was not clearer. (the reference to `Reflect`)

Comment: What is `stage`? If it's the original `new Stage()`, it should work. If it's `this.stage`, you also would need to refer to `this.stage.items[1]` for that item that you activate.